# how I can mange my text in child-listview?

Tags: java, android

In my application I have a listview and my child-listview is included an ImageButton and a Textview.
I have two problems:
first problem is that my textview's text appears behind the Imageview.and it doesn't show the whole text cause part of text is behind the imagebutton.
and the second one is that , although I used margintop my imagebutton doesn't move at all. I want to move it in a center of my list-item.

```
enter code here

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/lineItem"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.example.articalonlistiner.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/childButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/share" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/childTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        />
```

Is there anyone to suggest any way?

Comment: child lsitview means expandable listview? can you post you output screen?

Comment: sry I don't have enough score to share image. No it's simple list-view , it's just a name.

Comment: @diva I think s(he)'s pointing to the listview's list item as the child.

Comment: yeah exactly. it's right

Comment: ok , you  could upload anywhere and put the link on comments to explain you output image

Comment: and it seesm that you didint posted complete xml layout since i could see closing RelativeLayout

Comment: here is my link plz take a look at it     http://oi61.tinypic.com/qs0gly.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) use this: android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/childButton"

sample code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lineItem"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.articalonlistiner.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/childButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_drawer_map" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/childTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="sample text ..."
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/childButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2) use android:layout_centerVertical="true"